# Preg_match for alternative values in regex php

Tags: php, regex, match, preg-match

I want to match one of two posibilities in a regex.

```
$regex = "/^(& (sot-(<pagination>[0-9]+)) | (dorer-(<pagination>[0-9]+)) )? &?$/";
preg_match($regex, "&sot-6", $matches);
```

This regex should match for values like:

```
&sot-4
&dorer-56&
&sot-281&
&dorer-0
```

Which means "&"("sot-" or "dorer-")(number)(optional "&")

But (text)-(number) isn't the single format. That's why I need an extended regex format.

But it doesn't match at all.
What should I do?

Comment: The spaces are meaningful in regex. Add `x` modifier to make them formatting. Or, remove them. Also, named groups are defined with `(?<name>...)` or `(?P<name>...)`, but to have two groups with the same name you need to add `J` modifier. Try `'~^&(?:p-(?<pagination>[0-9]+)|page-(?<pagination>[0-9]+))?&?$~J'`, see https://regex101.com/r/gjK4rb/1

Comment: Get rid of the space around the groups.

Comment: I struggle to see the matching system, that you're after. So even if I were to produce a working regex-example for you, I wouldn't know if it would work in all cases. Are those cases that you've laid out, the absolutely only cases that the regex will get as input, - or are there a system? ... If so, - please update the answer, so a wholesome solution can be provided.

Comment: I've made it easy for you to understand the regex.

Comment: I edited now so you can understand the pattern.

Comment: Yeah, the `^&p(?:age)?-(?<pagination>[0-9]+)&?$` is the shortest after delving deeper into the pattern.

Comment: Not like that. "p" and "page" are just random text for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "random text"?

Comment: It is not necesary to be "p" and "page". Can be anything else there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this shorter regex that works with all of your test cases:

```
^&[^-]+-(?<pagination>\d+)&?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/po75xG/2/)

You may want to add more details in question if this is not matching your requirements.

**RegEx Details:**

- `^&`: Match `&` at line start
- `[^-]+`; Match 1+ non-hyphen characters
- `-`: Match a hyphen
- `(?<pagination>\d+)`: Match 1+ digits and capture it in group named `pagination`
- `&?$`: Match optional `&` before end

Comment: It is not necesary to be "p" and "page". Can be anything else there.

Comment: My bad. I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you. But (text)-(number) isn't the single format. That's why I need the extended regex format. Sorry for that.